# libb64 C routines proper usage

Tags: winapi, base64

I am having trouble with the C routines in [libb64](http://libb64.sourceforge.net/), here is my code:

```
    base64_encodestate state;
    int outBufLen = 2 * nInBuf;
    *outBuf = new char[outBufLen];

    base64_init_encodestate(&state);
    int r1 = base64_encode_block(inBuf, nInBuf, *outBuf, &state);
    int r2 = base64_encode_blockend(*outBuf, &state);
    base64_init_encodestate(&state);
```

This puts the = at the beginning, not at the end.

So I tried this:

```
    base64_encodestate state;
    int outBufLen = 2 * nInBuf;
    *outBuf = new char[outBufLen];

    base64_init_encodestate(&state);
    int r1 = base64_encode_block(inBuf, nInBuf, *outBuf, &state);
    int r2 = base64_encode_blockend(*outBuf+ r1, &state);
    base64_init_encodestate(&state);
```

This works, but not for "large" (~800KB text) files, then it skips the end = entirely. In that case base64_encode_blockend(code_out,state), enters case step_C where state->result = 0. I tried writing the b64 data to a file using the size reported by the libb64 functions, but it misses the end or is impartial. Im not sure.

I'm pretty much fed up with this. I based my code on the struct encode and decode.

Also do anyone know if there is a Windows API for base64 encode/decode? I am not using any C++ standard stuff, thats why I don't use the structs.

Comment: Your last chunk of code looks perfectly fine. What makes you think it "misses the end" or is "impartial"? (Did you make sure to write out `r1+r2` bytes? Do you realize that not all base64 encoded data ends with an `=`?)

Comment: Turns out a combination of limitation of viewing data in the IDE and IXMLDOMDocument's get_xml threw me off.